# Simulate a click in the ribbon toolbar of visio by using vba

Tags: vba, visio

I'm looking for a way to simulate a click on a button (Synchronize All) from an addin (http://visguy.com/vgforum/index.php?topic=6086.msg24731#msg24731) in the ribbon toolbar of Visio within VBA-Code.

> Please look at this picture for understanding: http://img4.picload.org/image/cpcgidr/ribbon.png

A pragmatic approach of mine was to use the "sendkeys"-function, because it's easy and sufficient. The problem with this approach is, i cannot navigate to the main-button (marked as 3. in the picture) by using the shortcuts "ALT+V" and "B" via sendkeys, i'm only able to navigate to the "conflicts panel" button as a subitem of "Synchronize All" (marked as 2. in the picture).

Does somebody have an idea how to click on the main-button (marked as 3. in the picture) via sendkeys or in a different way?

I'm just use this:

```
SendKeys "%v", True

SendKeys "b", True

SendKeys "{ENTER}", True
```

Please help me out with this, i've googled a lot without any results...

Best regards

Joerg

Comment: Did you try to record a macro and check its contents? See https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/8a46bc84-d8f2-4ee7-b765-3172c5055115/visio-2010-macro-recorder?forum=visiogeneral

Comment: Hi  stribizhev, thanks for your reply. Unfortunately the macro recorder doesn't record anything about that :( Is there a code snippet to achieve it?

Comment: Have you tried something like `Application.CommandBars.Item(x).Controls(y).Execute`? First, loop through all command bars, then find the necessary control, and try executing it.

Comment: Hey stribizhev, thank you very much for your help! I've never worked with ribbon controls, and i haven't any idea how to dive into this area of vba... Do you please have a code example or a link for me?

Comment: MsgBox Application.COMAddIns.Item("BackSync") <- Prints out "BackSync" how can i then trigger the button?

Comment: If you want to access the COM add-in inner methods like this, you need to know the method name(s) and their accessibility. See examples here: https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2013/11/27/use-excel-vba-macros-addins/#access-objects. that is why I checked the command bar option (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff860604.aspx), and it leads further to MS Fluent user interface: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff860604.aspx. I am sorry, but this is all I can say for now :(

Answer (score 0):

The author of that tool has implemented that trigger into that programm an has recompiled it, as you can see here: http://unmanagedvisio.com/products/backsync-backward-visio-data-synchronization/